# How is memory usage and limit determined for concurrent users

Tags: php

I need my curiosity to be cleared on php memory_limit

I included a file `memory.php` in my `index.php` file
Below is the script i used  memory.php, used to get the memory usage of a page.

```
<?php function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
 $units = array("b", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb");
 $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
 $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024)); 
 $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1); 
 $bytes /= (1 << (10 * $pow));
 return round($bytes, $precision) . " " . $units[$pow];
 } 

print formatBytes(memory_get_peak_usage());
?>
```

My index.php uses `500KB` memory.

in my `.htaccess` file i added this line

`php_value memory_limit 2M`

What i am curious about is that i read about users `concurrent` action on a page.

My question is that:

1. for example, if 5 users opened my index.php concurrently, is the memory usage combined i.e 5x500KB=2.5MB or the 500KB memory is for each user and doesn't matter if even 10 users opened my index.php concurrently
2. If the memory usage is combined for all users do i still have to change my `.htaccess` to a larger memory limit.

I have searched on stackoverflow for similar questions but i need a layman's explaination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each request that comes in is handled by your web server (ex. Apache). Now, depending on how the webserver is configured it *forks a new process* for each request.

> php_value memory_limit 2M

That individual process that reads and handles the PHP script is allowed to consume up to 2mb.

Here's a decent write-up. https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/

> PHP memory_limit is per-script, just as a highway’s speed limit is
> per-vehicle. For example, although PHP’s memory limit may be set high
> to 1GB, that does not mean that scripts will pile up to use that 1GB.

So, as an example, if 10 users all hit */index.php* at the same time, your web server would be using 10x 500kb (5mb) of memory in total, but it would be fine because each one is allowed to reach 2mb before and error is thrown.

> 1. for example, if 5 users opened my index.php concurrently, is the memory usage combined i.e 5x500KB=2.5MB or the 500KB memory is for
>    each user and doesn't matter if even 10 users opened my index.php
>    concurrently

The question is worded a bit weird, but no, PHP's memory limit is per process/request so you'll be OK. Each person would be allowed to consume up to 2mb in memory.

> 2. If the memory usage is combined for all users do i still have to
>    change my .htaccess to a larger memory limit.

It is not combined.

Finally, PHP's default memory limit (128mb) is fine for most applications. My recommendation is to leave it unless you have a good reason to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I now understood it.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP manual description of `memory_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) says:

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate.

When this says "a script", it's not referring to a particular URL or file on disk, it's referring to a particular *execution* of that script - most commonly, a particular request to your web server.

So if you have multiple users requesting the same page, they each get an "allowance" of 2 megabytes (which is a *very* low limit on a modern server!).

Note that this does *not* mean that 2 megabytes are pre-allocated for each request. What it means is that if PHP decides it needs more than that, it will immediately stop processing the page, leaving the user with a plain white page, and you with an error in your logs.

Comment: But since the page uses less than 600KB memory usage, i guess the 2M limit should be enough?

Comment: @Theconcise Sure, but what do you gain by limiting it to that? I've added a paragraph to my answer to address a possible confusion.